# Import not found in VueJS/TypeScript with gRPC-Web

Tags: typescript, vue.js, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-web

I've created a simple VueJS application and am trying to implement a example for a file upload.

I am using the following proto file:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

message File {
  bytes content = 1;
}

message MetaData {
  string name = 1;
  string type = 2;
}

message FileUploadRequest {
  oneof request {
    MetaData metadata = 1;
    File file = 2;
  }
}

enum Status {
  PENDING = 0;
  IN_PROGRESS = 1;
  SUCCESS = 2;
  FAILED = 3;
}

message FileUploadResponse {
  string name = 1;
  Status status = 2;
}

service FileUploadService {
  rpc upload(stream FileUploadRequest) returns(FileUploadResponse);
}
```

First I generate the client stub:

```bash
protoc -I=${DIR:-./api/} fileUpload.proto \
   --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:${OUT_DIR:-./api} \
   --grpc-web_out=import_style=typescript,mode=grpcwebtext:${OUT_DIR:-./api}
```

Which generates three files in the api directory:

```
├── api
│   ├── FileUploadServiceClientPb.ts
│   ├── fileUpload_pb.d.ts
|   ├── fileUpload.proto
│   └── fileUpload_pb.js
└── src
    ├── App.vue
    └── main
        ├── services
        │   └── fileService.ts
        └── views
```

I am now trying to implement the generated client code in the FileService:

```js
import { FileUploadServiceClient } from '../../../api/FileUploadServiceClientPb';
import { FileUploadRequest, FileUploadResponse, MetaData } from '../../../api/fileUpload_pb';

export default class FileService {

    constructor(readonly fileUploadClient: FileUploadServiceClient) { }

    uploadFile(file: File): Promise<FileUploadResponse | null> {
        ...
        this.fileUploadClient.upload(request, {}, (err, response) => {
        ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

The following two problems occur

1. import of messages and types does not seem to work, `Uncaught SyntaxError: import not found: MetaData`.
2. import of FileUploadServiceClient works but it does not recognize the upload method.

I am using libprotoc 3.20.1 and protoc-gen-grpc-web 1.3.1

I have already googled a bit but did not find a solution that could help me:

- https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/issues/431
- https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/issues/462

Different configurations of import_style and mode for grpc-web_out unfortunately did not solve the problem either. By the way, generating the server-side code in a quarkus application works exactly as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I also did not had success using the protoc-gen-grpc-web plugin. The protobuf-ts plugin was much nicer to use and actually worked:
https://github.com/timostamm/protobuf-ts/blob/master/MANUAL.md
(This is a link to their manual.)

The packages I used were:

- @protobuf-ts/runtime
- @protobuf-ts/plugin (I am pretty sure this can be a dev dependency)
- @protobuf-ts/grpcweb-transport (for creating the transport object used to create the client)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I'm still a bit overwhelmed by all the different libraries available. I am honestly wondering if gRPC-Web is already production ready for enterprise applications. I also tried the latest version of protobuf 21.x with protobuf-javascript, that doesn't seem to work at all.